# Add functions to a class contained in another package

Tags: java, design-patterns

I received a package from one of my collaborators, I want to add a function to a particolar class of this package, without modify the class in the package, or the package hitself. 
I was thinking of using a decorator, but if I do that, I must modify the class and the package, how can I do? Any suggestion?

Comment: "*I was thinking of using a decorator, but if I do that, I must modify the class and the package*" -  Why exactly? The simplest form of a decorator is to extend the to decorated class and just forward all method to an instance of the decorated class. If you really have to change a class or package and have no way to request some changes to the package, the only way would be byte code manipulation.

Comment: Thank you Turing85, that's probably the solution i was searching for, I still do not have much experience, except the scholastic one, so I thought of the classic Decorator in which you have to create an interface etc .... in the package, Thank you i will try to do what you sugget